# Switching iOS individual to Enterprise

Tags: ios, enterprise-distribution

I have got a standard iOS individual developer license for $99. Now I am in need of iOS Enterprise license which requires $299. Can I use the existing license for Enterprise distribution itself( By paying only $199) or Do I need to get new license?

Please suggest me.

Comment: This sounds like a question for the Apple developers forum (devforums.apple.com) as it concerns Apple policy. You are more likely to get a definitive answer there.

Answer (score 2):

You need a new license, and remember you must be a company or organization with a D-U-N-S number to apply for one.

More information can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/enterprise.html

This piece of information basically says you need a separate Apple ID to join each program, hence you can't 'upgrade'

> Can I use the Apple ID associated with my iOS Enterprise account to join another program?
>
> No. The Apple ID associated with an iOS Enterprise Program cannot be used for a standard iOS or Mac Developer Program.